# error:PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ora-00904

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pls_check2 AS
  PROCEDURE check_proc(p_item_cat       NUMBER,
                       p_sub_cat        NUMBER,
                       p_pack_is        NUMBER,
                       p_pack_name      NUMBER,
                       v1           OUT NUMBER,
                       v2           OUT NUMBER,
                       v3           OUT NUMBER,
                       v4           OUT NUMBER);

  PROCEDURE package_info1(param1 NUMBER, param2 NUMBER, param3 NUMBER);
END pls_check2;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pls_check2 AS
  v1  NUMBER;
  v2  NUMBER;
  v3  NUMBER;
  v4  NUMBER;

  PROCEDURE check_proc(p_item_cat       NUMBER,
                       p_sub_cat        NUMBER,
                       p_pack_is        NUMBER,
                       p_pack_name      NUMBER,
                       v1           OUT NUMBER,
                       v2           OUT NUMBER,
                       v3           OUT NUMBER,
                       v4           OUT NUMBER) IS
    CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT ic.id
        FROM itemcategory ic
       WHERE ic.id = p_item_cat;
  BEGIN
    v1 := p_item_cat;
    v2 := p_sub_cat;
    v3 := p_pack_is;
    v4 := p_pack_name;

    FOR c_p IN c1 LOOP
      INSERT INTO master_product_table
        (SELECT NULL,
                NULL,
                package_info1(c_p.id, v2, v3)
           FROM package);
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('hello');
  END;

  PROCEDURE package_info1(param1 NUMBER, param2 NUMBER, param3 NUMBER) IS
    v_is_incentivized  VARCHAR2(20);
  BEGIN
    SELECT is_incentivized
      INTO v_is_incentivized
      FROM package pk
     WHERE pk.id = 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('hi');
  END;
END pls_check2;
```

---

On compilation following error comes:

```
Error(18,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(33,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Comment: you have a table named "package". You shouldn't use [keywords as identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm)

Comment: ohh yes i do have a table named package its a business requirement i can't change it

Comment: this code still gives me the same error when i check code seems to be fine.

Comment: @user3751229 That's a very stupid business requirement. Can't you tell them that you need to prefix / suffix it (e.g. naming it `TAB_PACKAGE`) ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a `PROCEDURE` from SQL. That's not allowed (because it doesn't really make sense). Change `package_info1` to

```
function package_info1(param1 NUMBER, param2 NUMBER, param3 NUMBER)
    return number;
```

in the package header and to

```
function package_info1(param1 NUMBER, param2 NUMBER, param3 NUMBER)
    return number IS
  v_is_incentivized  VARCHAR2(20);
  BEGIN
    SELECT is_incentivized
      INTO v_is_incentivized
      FROM package pk
     WHERE pk.id = 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('hi');
    RETURN 1;
  END;
```

in the package body, and it will compile. Nevertheless, I'd really recommend you rename your `PACKAGE` table - that name is going to cause you pain without end.